# A strange exception in while using RequestFactory and Objectify

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, objectify

I had a look at the example from Google IO [gwtgae2011](http://code.google.com/p/gwtgae2011/) and got it working. I tried to add some functionality to the project and was constantly getting exception from server (onFailure method was invoked) and the stacktrace is

```
19:47:36.070 [ERROR] [crowd] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect.processPayload(AbstractRequestContext.java:299)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$4.onTransportSuccess(AbstractRequestContext.java:951)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.DefaultRequestTransport$1.onResponseReceived(DefaultRequestTransport.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
......stacktrace

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Server Error: No class 'com.trial.gwtgae.server.domain.Sketch2' was registered
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Receiver.onFailure(Receiver.java:36)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequest.onFail(AbstractRequest.java:113)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect.processPayload(AbstractRequestContext.java:271)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$4.onTransportSuccess(AbstractRequestContext.java:951)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.DefaultRequestTransport$1.onResponseReceived(DefaultRequestTransport.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
...more stacktrace
```

I created exact clone of class Sketch called Sketch2 and created clones of SketchDao, SketchProxy and SqetchRequest in my RequestFactory interface.

Exception is anyway thrown. (I tried to recompile, restart, clean generated files, tried using IDEA - same problem)
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: try to look at the line numbers thrown by the exception. This exception is often thrown when you have little stupid mistakes like when you try to add a row to a grid that is to small. Maybe you imported something wrong?

Comment: there are no my lines of code in the exception. Every clone is in the same package as it's original Sketch classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register classes that you want to use with objectify. Something like this:

```
factory.register(com.trial.gwtgae.server.domain.Sketch2.class);
```

Comment: I've found nothing about registering classes to factory. RequestFactory has no method called register. And even the original example with Sketches doesn't register any class.

Comment: http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/ObjectifyFactory.html#register(java.lang.Class)

Comment: I'm talking about objectify. You must register all entity classes.

Comment: You can also use ObjectifyService to register classes http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/ObjectifyService.html#register(java.lang.Class)